# Can't click overlapped element within a popup(not main window),how to scroll it to view?

Tags: webdriver

[image]

As you can see,I can click the first check box(PRODUCT-323),but can't click the second.After a long
trying,I find it is because the second doesn't get scrolled to view(Is it intented by tool design or a bug?).So how to scroll this popup div to ensure the second get shown?

Actually,I have tried this,but failed

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById("pupop").scrollTo(0,30)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share which version of WebDriver are you using?
If I remember correctly, Version 2.16 or so had a known issue with locators not scrolling into view. The reason being,, they were using the position co-ordinates of the center of the element to bring focus and in this case, the center is hidden from view. This was solved in later versions.

There are a couple of approaches.
1) Try to perform some action on an Element that is completely hidden from view.This will bring the element fully into view and you will be able to access it.
In this case, try to access the checkbox in 3rd or the 4th row, you will be able to bring focus there. Then access the 2nd row.
2) Do a Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize() [This is in c#]. This will also bring the element into view.

It is a good practice to avoid a window with both scroll-bars. By maximizing it you will reduce the window for such errors.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: I am using selenium-2.25,and this is a div popup,not main window

Comment: The issue can be fixed easily through javascript. Using ExecuteJavascript method and perform the button click operation. If the popup's resize is possible, then I would suggest that resizing the popup to a slightly larger size. But if its not possible, then try to access the 3rd row, say Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector ("div.popup tr"))[3].Click(). This will bring the 2nd row into view. and you will be able to perform the actual action you want.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try the keyboard options?? ctrl+ down arrow through script???
Or in the worst case use tab to focus on to that checkbox.. I works in OpenScript and RFT this way.

Answer (score 0):

1) To click the second checkbox: You can use the xpath to find that element. In xpath you can easily get the table row id for each checkbox which will gets incremented in their ID.
2) To scroll you can use the below code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webdriver;
js.executeScript("scroll(0,0);");
```